# jQuery not working in IE - simplacart implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm relatively new to jQuery so apologies if the answer is obvious.

I have a shopping cart using simpleCart js, when adding an item to the cart in FF and Chrome everything runs smoothly but IE(9) doesn't seem to manage it.

http://www.peaknature.co.uk/cart/

The main piece of script is:

**UPDATED**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".simpleCart_shelfItem").hover(function(event) {
    $(this).find('.tooltip').stop(true,true).show();
});
$(".simpleCart_shelfItem").mouseleave(function(event) {
    $(this).find('.tooltip').stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
});
//Cart info (all items in cart)
$(".cartInfo").toggle(function(){
    $("#cartPopover").show();
    $(".cartInfo").addClass('open');
}, function(){
    $("#cartPopover").hide();
    $(".cartInfo").removeClass('open');
});


$(".shelf .simpleCart_shelfItem:eq(0)").css('left', '20px');
$(".shelf .simpleCart_shelfItem:eq(1)").css('left', '250px');
$(".shelf .simpleCart_shelfItem:eq(2)").css('left', '480px');
$(".shelf .simpleCart_shelfItem:eq(3)").css('left', '710px');
$(".shelf .simpleCart_shelfItem:eq(4)").css('left', '20px').css('top', '170px');


});
```

I know IE can be funny with selectors etc but I'm not sure what's wrong.

Any help is much appreciated.

Chris

Comment: I don't have an IE here on Linux but the page is not usable for me since the hover ofer the images disappears when i try to select a size. Therefore, I'm never able to chose something from the dropdown since it disappears for me (latest Chrome stable)

Comment: @DrColossos I Dont see that and I also on latest Chrome (Windows Version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what is happening is the simplecart logic is running before its ready, add this round all your code (and remove the script tags).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //All your code here.
});
```

This will sure everything is loaded before attempting to use it.

**UPDATE**

After looking at ie9 console it shows the following error

```
SEC7112: Script from https://raw.github.com/
wojodesign/simplecart-js/master/simpleCart.js was blocked due to mime type mismatch
```

This is likely due to the fact that raw.github provides a raw text file to your without telling you it is a js file.

Try setting the `type="text/javascript"` on the `<script></script>` tags to rectify

On a side note I am unsure if you are infact the owner of wojodesigns or not however it could be better to use a local version (local to your server) to ensure it not changed without you knowing (even more important if it anything to do with ecommerce).

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick response. I wrapped the code above in the document ready code - there were no <script> tags originally but I'm still experiencing the same issue. I've uploaded the new js file so you can see.

Comment: @ChrisJ I have updated my answer with a possible solutions... if this helps please upvote and/or mark as correct answer :)

Comment: Sorted! Thank you. Indeed, you're right about having a local copy which I've rectified. That was on the todo list once everything else was working! I added the script type too and IE seems to like that. Thanks for the help.